# How does containsValue in map work

Tags: java, methods

How does containsValue in java work? Does it compare the given object with the values already in teh map? If so why doesn't this work?

I have the following class: `class Node{
    Integer n;
    Integer wt;
    String v;
}`

and use this mapping: Map map = new HashMap();

This piece of code does not work as intended :
    `

```
n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
wt = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
depth = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
set = "";
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
   set = set+st.nextToken()+" ";
Node nd = new Node();
nd.n = n;
nd.wt = wt;
nd.v = set;
if(!map.containsValue((Object)nd)){
map.put(key,nd);
key = key+1;
}`
```

There are still duplicate values in the mapping.

Comment: And how it was actually intended?

Comment: That if there is a value that has already been mapped then it will not be inserted into the hashmap again.

Comment: Please post the equals and hashCode methods for class Node. This is one of the situations in which hashCode correctness really matters.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to implement `hashCode` and `equals` if you are working with HashMap, otherwise each new object is a new and different object, no matter the values it is made of.

Comment: Alright, then why does the definition say : boolean containsValue(Object value) Returns true if this map maps one or more keys to the specified value. If it takes Object value as argument then shouldn't the comparison be in terms of values that the object is made of? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using Maps and Sets, you must make sure that the classes for your values (and in the case of Map, also the keys, of course) implement adequate [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) methods. Without explicitly providing them, the system can have no real understanding of semantic equivalence for your application.